# Simple results involving many branches of mathematics

Tags: geometry, polynomials, complex-numbers, soft-question, meta-math

[Marden's theorem](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MardensTheorem/): Given a triangle in the complex plane, a polynomial $p$ can be made from the vertices. The roots of derivative $p'$ give the foci of the [Steiner inellipse](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinerInellipse.html), which is tangent to the midpoints of the original triangle.

That simple result ties together complex numbers, triangles, derivatives, polynomials and conic sections.

[Euler's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_identity), $e^{i \pi} +1=0$, also covers numerous branches of mathematics.

What other simple results are similarly far-reaching?

Comment: [FLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_Last_Theorem) is far-reaching, involving very many things. However, only the statement is "simple".

Comment: Useful for the FLT, the [Riemann-Roch theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem#Riemann.E2.80.93Roch_theorem_for_algebraic_curves) has a version in Riemann surfaces and in finite fields, making a link between geometry, algebra and complex analysis.

Comment: [Monsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsky's_theorem) looks like a good example.

Comment: there is also a Riemann-Roch theorem for combinatorial graphs and metric graphs, due to Baker and Norine https://mattbaker.blog/2013/10/18/riemann-roch-for-graphs-and-applications/